# Mostrar Featured Image com crop no index.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugin, wordpress-theme

Estou programando neste link http://catalogos.axitech.com.br/ e preciso  resolver esta estrutura visto que 1 a cada 4 quadrados tem uma imagem destacada praticamente o dobro do tamanho que as outras imagens.

Eu sei mais ou menos a solução, não sei como poderia programar para chegar ao resultado mas acho que o melhor jeito é centralizar a imagem no meio horizontal e vertical e fazer um *crop* da mesma.

Algum *plugin* poderia me ajudar a realizar esta tarefa?

Comment: Já foi resolvido ? Se foi poste a solução como resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Criar um segundo css para o div (para o destaque)

2) Alterar o loop para incluir um contador

3) Dentro do loop, de 4 em 4, usa o segundo css de div para o output.